# Apple Pay - Pass book empty

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, braintree, applepay

recently my app got failed in an Apple Review , for Apple Pay , mentioning "Specifically, we found that your app provide the Apple Pay button for devices without Apple Pay being set up."... Clueless :( I built the way , button "Buy with Apple Pay" will display , when

```
     [PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments]
```

returns one (true) & Braintree validation success on devices like iPhone 6, 6+. Though, Passbook is empty , above canMakePayments returns "true" always. I suspect , this could the reason for Apple rejection. But, do you think we can fix this from our end by any other means? Or ,Shall I appeal for it? If I am on wrong path, correct me.

Also, I couldn't get clear on this statement what Apple Doc says on it.

"On devices that support making payments but don’t have any payment cards configured, the canMakePayments method returns YES because the hardware and parental controls allow making payments, but the canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks: method returns NO regardless of network."

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion -- Verify whether  Apple Pay is configured for your app, ensure that "Apple Pay" is "On" in the Capabilities section of  target settings, and that it has a merchant identifier!

Comment: @Vizllx How to do that, programmatically ? It will be ON for capable devices like iPhone 6 , 6 + etc though Pass book doesn't have card right?

Comment: It has nothing to do with programming,It's just validating the project settings.

Comment: @Vizllx Ok thats done.. I want Programmatically a way to evaluate eligible devices like iphone 6, 6+ etc without Passbook Setup. Because here it fails :(... canMakePayments returns true always.

Comment: Apple Pay is now available (as of today) on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, and active only in US.

Comment: Yeah!... But, Still if you give Shipping Address as an International Country It will proceed! Thats weird! ... Raised bug report already. Ok Lets .. find out solution for above case !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what the reason for an issue! Actually not an Apple Bug, its our own implementation bug.

Just posting for [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController/canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks) -  Like me , many might have missed this, hope this will help others.

`canMakePayments` - Will return "YES" ( True / 1 ) irrespective of card configuration.

`canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks` - Will return "NO" , if card NOT configured or NOT configured properly.

So, for my case I should check both... If both should be TRUE then only I need to make Button "Apple Pay" visible. Let me request and see what happens!

Comment: You are correct. canMakePayments is more of a "is the device capable?" (an iPhone 4 will always return NO, for example) and canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks is "is it available right now?"